# What site can I ask for product recommendations on?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm in need of some FTP software for my Chromebook and wanted to ask for a product recommendation but after reading the articles in the help centre, I realized this sort of question would be classed as off-topic. Is there another site on Stack Exchange where these questions should be asked?

Comment: There are some questions over on [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ftp) but be sure to read their helpcenter first and specially how to ask. When still in doubt ask on their meta first.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found [this page](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) especially helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have precise requirements about what you want to ask you can ask in Software Recommendations, specially this one [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). You should be very specific of what you want, and for what you want to use it.